# Laravel Backpack cache

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-backpack

I ran `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`, now all the styles to the pages are not reflecting. Is there anything I need to link properly or run in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

did you follow all the instalation steps ? Did you published Backpack files ?

Please try `php artisan vendor:publish` and then select the `BackpackServiceProvider` or alternativelly: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\CRUD\BackpackServiceProvider"`

Let me know,
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is solved now. I had to run php artisan optimize, php artisan config:clear, php artisan view:clear, php artisan config:cache, php artisan view:cache randomly and it works now. Guess I don't really what solved the issue but it works now